# Removing NA from geom-bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could I remove NA responses from using the following code?

```
bar <- ggplot(newdata)
bar + stat_summary(
  aes(x = preferred.actual.factor, y = lifesatisfaction, fill = gender),
  fun.y = mean,
  geom = "bar",
  position = "dodge"
) + stat_summary(
  aes(x = preferred.actual.factor, y = lifesatisfaction, fill = gender),
  fun.data = mean_cl_normal,
  geom = "errorbar",
  position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),
  width = 0.2
) + labs(x = "Time Mismatch", y = "Life Satsifaction")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some data to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it from your dataframe, then you could try these options before plotting.

To remove cases with NA in any column:

```
newdata <- na.omit(newdata)
```

To remove cases with NA in a specific column:

```
newdata <- newdata[!is.na(newdata$your_column_name),]
```